# My button onclick event in HTML will call my function but not return the alert()

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML (the part to get input and create the onclick event):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="addressInput"></input>
    <button type='button' onclick="getNearestStation()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is my JS (the part handling the onclick event and alert()ing an answer)

```
function getNearestStation() {
  var addressInput = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
  geocoder.geocode({ address: addressInput, limit: 1 }, function(err, res) {
    var geoLat = res[0]["latitude"];
    var geoLon = res[0]["longitude"];
    addressCoord = { latitude: geoLat, longitude: geoLon };
    counter = 0;
    coordList = {};
    alert(coordList);
    for (item of lat) {
      coordList[text[counter]] = { latitude: item, longitude: lon[counter] };
      counter += 1;
    }
    var distances = [];
    orderDistance = geolib.orderByDistance(addressCoord, coordList);
    for (dict of orderDistance) {
      distances.push(dict["distance"]);
    }
    var distance = Math.min(...distances);
    var place = "";
    for (dict of orderDistance) {
      if (dict["distance"] == distance) {
        place = dict["key"];
      }
    }
    alert(
      "The nearest subway station is " +
        Math.min(...distances) +
        " meters away at " +
        place
    );
  });
}
```

I inserted `alert(addressInput);` the line after I assigned addressInput and it alerted properly, but for some reason my alert message at the end of the function does nothing. It would mean the world to me if someone explained where I went wrong.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Instead of all those loops, you can sort the `orderDistance` array, then use the first element of the sorted array.

Comment: @Barmar No, when I run the JavaScript code I just get "[Running] node "c:\xampp\htdocs\project map.js"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.497 seconds"" Would changing the loops make the alert() go off correctly?

Comment: No, the loops aren't a problem, they're just inefficient.

Comment: You're running this in node.js, not a browser?

Comment: The alert is now inside the callback of the geocoder.geocode function. The callback will only be triggered if the gecoder.geocode function works. You mention node, but this code should run in a browser. The code above does not import a geocoder. Do you see errors in the browser console (open with Function Key 12 on Windows PC)?

Comment: I am running it in node.js with visual studio code I think (very new to coding haha), but I am also hosting my files with apache to see them in browser. I know the function is able to retrieve the input, I just don't know why alert() doesn't work once it's within the geocoder function.

Comment: @anneb I received these errors: https://imgur.com/a/DvSdn88 . Before the JS I showed in the original post I put `var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
let geolib = require('geolib');

var geocoder = NodeGeocoder({
  provider: 'opencage',
  apiKey: my api key 
});`  and  <script src="https://unpkg.com/opencage-api-client@0.3.0/dist/opencage-api.min.js"></script> is in the head of my HTML.

Comment: You show html with a button that calls javascript function getNearestStation(). You can only call in-browser javascript from a html button from inside a browser. It will not work from Node. Browsers do not support the 'require()'  syntax. The link you provided returns "cannot find file..."

Comment: Would this help my situation? https://github.com/browserify/browserify Sorry for all of the questions but I am very new to this and somewhat lost, I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @anneb I browserified my code using the command browserify main.js -o bundle.js and added bundle.js in source tags in the head of index.html, and now the graphs I made using Plot.ly are missing and the geocoder still does not work. I am completely lost at this point